# How to reset AnimatedVectorDrawable animations in Android when an Activity is returned to under version 23?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-animation

Scenario: I have a shape as an *AnimatedVectorDrawable* instance inside an *ImageView*. When this shape (*ImageView*) is clicked on, it performs an animation. After this animation ends, a new *Activity* is executed. Then, when using the return button on my smartphone, the first *Activity* is displayed. To make the *AnimatedVectorDrawable* appear in it's original state (with no animation applied), it's method reset() can be called above android sdk version 23. Example:

```
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        avdLogo.reset()
    }
```

*avdLogo* refers to the *AnimatedVectorDrawable* in question.

**How can I achieve the same below version 23**?

Answer (score 1):

Add `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` to your defaultConfig in the android section of your module’s build.gradle. like below

```
android {
     ........       
      ........

    defaultConfig {
       ........
       vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
```

It will support animated-vector drawable file to compatible use with APIs lower than Lollipop.

Comment: Nice to hear it. Happy coding

Comment: But then wouldn't you be using `AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat` which does not have a `reset` method?

Comment: When I add that and try to use `reset` I get `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method reset()V in class Landroid/graphics/drawable/AnimatedVectorDrawable; or its super classes`

Comment: Hi @IanButler, while using AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat, have you found the work around for reset() method?